# Surfacing results as they are printed on HTML Page

Tags: python, css, heroku, flask

I have a Python ***for*** ***loop*** that can print anywhere between 1 and 20 outputs. I am building a webapp (Flask / Heroku) and I would like to surface each output as it's printed in the loop on my HTML page. So MY HTML page would look like this (where each output is printed separately)...

```
Checking...
    output 1: not valid
    output 2: not valid
    output 4: not valid
    output 5: valid!
```

Usually, I would just pass however many variables into my HTML page:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template("main.html", output = output)
```

but it doesn't make sense to do this for each output printed as I would be calling the HTML page multiple times. Here is my for loop in case:

```
p = [p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13]
e = iter(p)

# run validation logic
 print "Checking..."
    for x in e:
        i = x+"@"+d
        has_mx = validate_email(i,check_mx=True)
        is_real = validate_email(i,verify=True)

        if (has_mx == False):
            print "no mx record"
            break
        elif (is_real and x == p0):
            print "catchall detected"
            break
        elif (x != p0):
            if is_real:
                print i, "probably valid" 
                break
            else:
                print i, "not valid"
```

Comment: If you are going to give the question a negative, please explain why. I think it's helpful for me to understand as I'm new to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call the page with multiple times - you just need to use [Flask's templating engine (Jinja2) to render your output](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for).  Something like this:

```
{# in validation.html #}
<ul>
{% for value, is_valid, validity_message in data %}
    <li>{{ value }}: {{ validity_message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will generate an unordered list of `value: validity_message` pairs:

```
<ul>
    <li>A: probably valid</li>
    <li>B: no mx record</li>
    <!-- ... etc. ... -->
</ul>
```

Some other suggestions:

- Use *descriptive* variable names.  It's obvious to you right now that `d` id a domain, but six months from now, it probably will not be.
- There's no need to call `iter` on a list - just iterate over the list itself.

Reworked code:

```
def validate_emails(names, domain, catchall):
    # run validation logic
    for name in names:
        email = name + "@" + domain
        has_mx = validate_email(email, check_mx=True)
        is_real = validate_email(email, verify=True)
        is_catchall = name == catchall

        if not has_mx:
            yield name, False, "no mx record"
            break
        elif is_real and is_catchall:
            yield name, False, "catchall detected"
        elif is_real and not is_catchall:
            yield email, True, "probably valid" 
        else:
            yield email, False, "not valid"
```

Which you could then use like this:

```
messages = validate_emails(["a", "b", "c"], "somedomain.com", "sales")
return render_template("validation.html", data=messages)
```